# Error: No valid exports main found in container environment

Tags: node.js, docker, graphql

It's been a few days since I'm trying to resolve this issue which blocks the deployment of my application.

A few days ago, I noticed an error in my CI/CD process due to an exited container issue which comes from this error:

```
Error: No valid exports main found for '/app/node_modules/graphql-tools'
at resolveExportsTarget (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:618:9)
at applyExports (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:499:14)
at resolveExports (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:548:12)
at Function.Module._findPath (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:650:22)
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:948:27)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:854:27)
at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1023:19)
at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:72:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/@graphql-modules/utils/src/get-schema-directive-from-directive-resolver.ts:1:1)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1128:30) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND'
}
```

The thing is when I run my application locally everything works. So I went inside the container to see if this folder exists which does exist. I tried to reproduce the error locally by using npm instead of yarn or use the same node version but I couldn't reproduce it.

Here is my dockerfile.dev which is quite simple:

```
FROM node:13.3.0-alpine AS base
WORKDIR /app
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install

COPY .babelrc ./
COPY src ./src

CMD ["npm", "run", "dev"]
```

**Resolved**

The error was due to using the node:13.3.0-alpine image, a change to node:lts-alpine resolved the issue.

Comment: Maybe an issue with the alpine image. Did you try to reproduce the error with the normal Docker Node image?

Comment: How are you running the container?  (One of the standard Node-in-Docker setups actively prevents Docker from seeing any changes in your `package.json` file.)

Comment: @Istnrs It works! I changed to the node:lts-alpine image and everything works perfectly. Seems like the 13.3.0 were causing trouble.